# Comparing negative value in VBA to produce pass and fail result

Tags: excel, vba, negative-number

I'm still new at VBA and this is a simple problem, but I'm comparing negative numbers who is greater or equal is "pass", else it "fail" for example if I inputed:

`40` is pass,
`20` is pass,
but if i input `-20` it shows "fail" which is it should "pass" while I put `-40` it "pass" which is it should "fail".

I don't know how to solve it because for me the condition is correct but the result isn't.

```
If Me.kepi4.Value >= "-30.70" Then
    MsgBox "The KEPI 4 Value Pass the Evaluation"
    Me.gd4.Value = "PASS"
    UserForm9.Show
Else
    MsgBox "Check Your Kepi 4 Evaluation Value"
    Me.gd4.Value = "FAIL"
    UserForm10.Show
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `"-30.70"` is a string/text and not a number. It should be `-30.70` instead.

Also you should turn your textbox value into a double `cDbl(Me.kepi4.Value)` so it is truned into a number that you can actually compare with mathematical operators `>=`.

It should look like this:

```
If cDbl(Me.kepi4.Value) >= -30.70 Then
```

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and fast respond solution.  I never use that cDbl before. Now it works to compare my values.

Comment: @IamOnlyaFish Then have a look at [Type conversion functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) if you never used them before.